# Local strong solution to Navier-Stokes equation by Galerkin method without using the eigenfunctions of the Stokes operator

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, navier-stokes

The existence of a local-in-time strong solution to the Navier-Stokes equations in a smoothly bounded domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ (say with no-slip boundary condition) can be obtained by a Galerkin method in a very similar way as one can prove the existence of Leray-Hopf weak solutions (if the initial velocity $u_0$ satisfies $u_0 \in V$, where $V$ is the closure in $H^1(\Omega)$ of  smooth, divergence free, and compactly supported (in $\Omega$) functions).

With local(-in-time) strong solution I mean a Leray-Hopf weak solution $u$ with
$$
\nabla u \in L^{\infty}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))
$$ where $T > 0$ might be very small.

One can for instance find the above mentioned Galerkin method based proof in Chapter 3 (Section 3.7, Theorem 3.11) of the book [1].  I do not know a freely accessible publication, but similar ideas appear in many publications on the subject.

**My question**: for getting a local strong solution through a Galerkin approach, is it really necessary to employ a Galerkin basis that consists of eigenfunctions for a corresponding Stokes problem? Or is it also possible to get a local strong solution by employing a similar Galerkin method while choosing other bases? Does anyone know a reference where this has been done or a reason why not?

**Remark 1**: For showing the existence of Leray-Hopf weak solutions by a Galerkin method one does not need a special basis, see Theorem 3.1 in Chapter 3 of the above stated reference. But concerning local strong solutions, I have so far never seen(but would really like to) a Galerkin argument where not a basis of eigenfunctions for a corresponding Stokes operator has been used. Of course, the advantage of using such eigenfunctions is clear: one gets better energy estimates for the approximating sequence which allows to obtain a strong solution in the limit. But it is not at all obvious to me whether this has to be done in this way. Maybe there is also a different way of getting sufficient estimates for Galerkin approximate solutions, maybe by taking a time derivative in the ODEs for the coefficients and further energy estimates(?).

**Remark 2**: I know that there are different ways to obtain a unique local strong solution, like mollification combined with the Leray-Schauder approach or fixed point arguments together with semigroup theory(where one uses again spectral properties of the governing linear operator), but I am really interested in the question whether one can employ a Galerkin argument without Stokes eigenfunctions and if I might just have never seen it while it is perfectly feasible.

**Reference**

[1] Roger Temam, *[Navier-Stokes equations. Theory and numerical analysis](https://mathscinet.ams.org/leavingmsn?url=https://doi.org/10.1090/chel/343)*, Reprinted with corrections (English), Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS), pp. xiv+408 (2001), ISBN: 0-8218-2737-5, [MR1846644](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1846644), [Zbl 0981.35001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0981.35001).